# Proving a result in a given field

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory

My thinking:

Due to the axiom describing closure of a field we know that there are four possibilities for the result.

Thanks

Comment: Find the addition and multiplication tables. They must be latin squares (negating the zero in the mult. table).

Comment: i just bombed my math final but i thought 1+1=2

Comment: @SakethMalyala: That is true... but in this field, $2=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Finite fields have finte non-zero characterisctic.

And characteristic of a field is a prime number.
Also characteristic of a field divides the order of the field.

Here order of the field is $4$, and the only prime that divides it is $2$, hence characteristic of this field is $2$, hence $1+1=0$ !!!

**Alternative way:**

Clearly, $ab=1$ as $ab$ can't equal $a$ or $b$(as then multiply by inverse to get a contradiction), also it can't equal $0$, as any field is also an integral domain and product of two non-zero elements is non-zero.

Since a field is also a group under addition, order of an element under addition divides the order of the field, now if order of the element $1$ is not $2$, then it's of course equal to $4$, hence $1$ is the generator of the field.

So $1+1+1+1=0$, W.L.O.G

$a=1+1$, $b=1+1+1$

So $ab=1+1+1+1+1+1=0+1+1=1+1$

So $ab\neq1$ (a contradiction)

Comment: I am working with fields that have addition and multiplication and elements 0 and 1. I haven't learnt finite fields.

Comment: My guess is that this is a question at the beginning of the study about field.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: This too hard for me to understand. I am trying to prove by showing the other possibilities are false.

Comment: this the easiest possible explanation, study more first

Answer (score 1):

Trying to exclude $1+1=a$ and $1+1=b$ is very hard if you don't understand the following. All I am using here are field axioms, the fact that $0 \cdot x = 0$, and the notion of "order of an element in a group".

$(F , + )$ is a group of order 4, so there exists some element of order 2. Let $x \in F$ be such element. $x$ has order 2 means that $x \neq 0$ and
$$x+x=0$$
Hence
$$(1+1)= (x^{-1} \cdot x) (1+1) = x^{-1}(x \cdot (1+1)) = x^{-1} \cdot (x+x) = x^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0$$

Comment: Can it be proven by showing that 1 + 1 cannot equal a, b or 1 so it must equal 0

Comment: I am familiar with field axioms but I am not familiar with order of an element in a group. Is there an easier way to arrive at the conclusion that x + x = 0?

Comment: The problem here is that you don't know what $a$ and $b$ are. You only know that the are different elements.

Comment: Also, could I show that 1 + 1 is not equal to a or b by using an addition table? That way I would be eliminating possibilities

Comment: Using only the addition table is useful, but it won't be enough. This is because you have to use the multiplicative property of $1$ (which distingishes it from $a,b$). Now, use the addition table and see that there is a nonzero element $x$ such that $x+x=0$. If $x=1$, you are done: otherwise conclude the proof using my argument.

Comment: I am not understanding how you arrive at the conclusion that x + x = 0 using the order of an element. Is there an easier way you can explain me, maybe using an addition table?

Comment: Sorry I am new to the study of fields

Comment: The order of an element just means how many times you add it to itself to get 0.  Using addition tables there are only two groups with four elements.  And in both of them there is some element x (other than 0)  so that x+x=0.  So 0=x+x=x (1+1).  If 1+1 =y !=0 you have xy=0 which is impossible for a field.

Comment: Could I use a + a = 0 or b + b =0 instead of x + x = 0

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's theorem applied to the additive group of the field we have
$$
1+1+1+1=0.
$$
Therefore, by distributivity,
$$
0=(1+1+1+1)=(1+1)(1+1)=(1+1)^2.
$$
So if $1+1\neq0$ we have found a zero divisor $1+1$. Fields don't have zero divisors, so this is a contradiction and we are left with $1+1=0$.

Comment: Alternative end game: $(1+1)^2=0$, so $1+1$ cannot have a multiplicative inverse. Therefore $1+1=0$.

Comment: A generalization of this argument shows that the characteristic of a field is either zero (=infinite) or a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider {1,a,b} which is a group under multiplication. 1 is the identity under multiplication. ab is 1 under multiplication as argued in the above answer.

Now, consider {0,1,a,b} . Try to find the additive inverse of 1. 0 is not the additive inverse obviously. Suppose a or b is additive inverse. Say a is the inverse

Then 1+a = 0
(Multiply with b )
1.b + a.b = 0.b
(Since, 1.b = b, 0.b = 0 and a.b = 1) 
b + 1 = 0
But additive inverse is unique. Hence a =b

But a$\neq$ b because they are distinct elements of the group .Contradiction

Similar contradictions if you start with b.So additive inverse of 1 is 1
Hence 1+1 = 0

Answer (score 0):

The elements $0,1,a,b $ form an additive group.  Either it is equivalent to $\mathbb Z_4$ and it is equivalent to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. If it is equivalent to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ then $1+1=0$

So we can assume it is equivalent to $Z_4$ and we can relable $0,1,a,b$ as $0,1,2,3$ and $1+1=2,2+1=3,$ etc.

But we can't make a field of this.

$2*2=2 (1+1)=2+2=0$.  But that would mean $1=\frac 12 *2*\frac 12*2=\frac 12*\frac 12 *2*2=\frac 12 *\frac 12 *0=0$.  A contradiction.

.....

Oh, I guess I should point out that when we relable $0,1,a,b$ as $0,1,2,3$ we don't have to map $1$ to $1$.  We could map $a$ or $b $ to $1$ and map $1$ to $2$ or $3$.  But $2+2=0$ so if we map $1$ to $2$ we have $1+1=0$.  If we map $1$ to $3$, we still have $3+3=2$ and a proof will still hold.

If $0,1,a,b $ is a field and $1+1=x\ne 0$ then $x+x=0$ as that is the only additive group possibility. And $0=x+x=x (1+1)=x*x $ which is impossible.

===

If $1+1=a $ then $1+b\ne 1,a,b$ so $1+b=0$ and $1+a=b $

$b+a\ne 0$ because $b+1=0$.  $b+a\ne b $. $b+a\ne a $. So $ b+a=1$.

$a+a\ne a $, $a+a\ne 1$ because $a+b=1$, $a+a\ne b $ because $a+1=b $.  So $a+a=0$

So $0=a+a=a (1+1)=a*a $.

So $0*\frac 1a =a*a*\frac 1a=a $

But $0*x+0*x=(0+0)x=0x $.  So $0x=0x+0x-0x=0x-0x=0$.

$a=0*\frac 1a =0$ which is a contradiction.

So $1+1\ne a $.

The exact same argument holds for $1+1\ne b$.